# How to use echarts visualMap to color Line depending on X-Axis Value?

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

Expected:

I want to divide single line into 2 parts based on x axis value.

Example, when x-value is greater than "2016-8" show dashed line as following

[image: Single line divided into 2 parts, solid and dashed]

Tried with ECharts visualMap, but it only works depending on y-axis value
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-aqi

Answer (score 0):

It seems VisualMap can only be used to change the color and/or symbol of the line.

#### Different colors on the same line using VisualMap on xAxis

If you don't specifically need to get a dashed line and you just want to use VisualMap on xAxis, you should set [`visualMap-piecewise.dimension`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap-piecewise.dimension) to 0 (0 being x and 1 being y in simple [x,y] series).

```js
visualMap: {
  dimension: 0,
},
```

Then you'll need to set your list of [pieces](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap-piecewise.pieces) depending on the type of xAxis ('time' or 'category'):

- 'time' : [full example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-sections&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWtJgDYFMBcya6GOAHmAQOQAiEAzmAE4QBGArpDLMAGawCiuAMZMIQiGACelADRF0dNizBkKsSgDEAhgGscsalrBbKRAL5z0YYMCyQQBVMQzMA5q5yMqW0vVnzYH3oABWAIaBUvQmcrSRB8dSFGYDo6U2czc0tYUgBBXzpHAKl4qkgAWxx_ZxZgNmgAEy1GSQBxLQdYHi0sOhxsiyJJfPoi5xKEygA3HrYq7PQgugAZLRYcLDGYnmBGcqNIqiQZrDmzWAB1dOJB5yXQ8MPomLpoDoImOYDM9FvYJuMAC0bOUCABtAJOGITKjhOgQBpVb5EAC6cim9DYPQAsu9ntZOgBWAAM2TcAAs1ABGUlEBoQSrQeEwAi09AgCA4IQ4QqwCHOKHOVwUNkxOwJaA4ADuBiMOAAFJQAEzEqkAFgAtMSAGxapWUACUADoTnMAPI8eUGhbEIS2XZUADEAE4AMwAYX4xIA7NUbjbBcRhQRJTLDCpFSr1VrdcT9cbTTgLVabehxXhQ7KI8rVZqdVrXYaTbMk5brQF0HasA71I7iTxiddfgGK7Bg7BM-GFTno_niYWEyXk-WYrB0525ZHczGtWqi4nh6nYFWa5Q6_Wm7A_uhA-h2xPs1G87G54PTqWU62V1E1w3G99smiiDs9gdPAQePURFBoPKQM0tHKOgDUDRgcDANhGDgA8FX_RhAOAo1rAASQAZTNVDRGgVwrSyIg6jAC0ACUtGwhJA2vJ1nWo65Mj-PpmB5cFIVbN5KioQQuVEcQpD9cY4kmLBwnmVs6HKGwwHJD5GDmJcAHo5NgEAwLASBPA1CBXGgXYcFbAEtHBMEYKnXtYypQ0ZFgV1iWJNE-WMntjz1CzYCVAAOWzLKM6Us27I8Z37FylRJOzvLDSdHIC09LKVbVPPsnyuxMpziUJILvVsp8MlRFAzAAbiAA)
- 'category' : [full example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-sections&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWtJgDYFMBcya6GOAHmAQOQAiEAzmAE4QBGArpDLMAGawCiuAMZMIQiGACelADRF0dNizBkKsSgDEAhgGscsalrBbKRAL5z0YYMCyQQBVMQzMA5q5yMqW0vVnzYH3oABWAIaBUvQmcrSRB8dSFGYDo6U2czc0tYUgBBXzpHAKl4qiEjHFdgRmls9BZgNmgAEy0agHEtB1geLSw6HDr0VuMCAG1KAAZJvGnZdUmARjxFgFZ5qYAmPABmSY3JnbwAFnWZBdXZ_YBdLKJJfPoi5xKEygA3PrYcf2cgugAMloWDgsM8YjxqgBbIyRKhIT5Yb5mWAAdXSxAsAX-oXCcOiMTo0C6BCY3wCmXQWOGRi0AC0bFDxgEnDFXlRwnQIM0fhSiNdsu96Gw-gBZEkEqygAirSZDNwACzUizlAWaEChOGgXJgBFVzhAEBwQhwhVgYwC6FZMVgrgo-ptsDsCUWQ2cQls1SoAGIAJw7ADC_EmAHZfjFqTFrTE7QRXZbiM68Js3cQPVgvepvZMePsE5HnNHnLHYCmE-gk7Adqn0OnM5RszmMRlU0XiCXq-XYHWog3c3mbQXYAKAo0wAB5HgAJS00A84Pdnt7ft9vubsEpG-yA2YpuZhYTxM1VEExtE4ik4ZecTeWHCP1TdChNjACtJjG-qYA9F_YCBGDgYCQJ4AC0ECuNA1Q4AmIxaOMexyqWAAciGbLK5ybAAbKhIaTCOGT8igZgANxAA)

#### Dashed line on half the series

If you specifically need to get this :

> when x-value is greater than "2016-8" show dashed line as following

You can split your series in 2 different series and affect a different line style to each of them:

1. Series 1: date <= "2016-8" (solid line)
2. Series 2: date >= "2016-8" (dashed line)

[Here is a working example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-aqi&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWtJgDYFMBcya6GOAHmAQOQAiEAzmAE4QBGArpDLMAGawCiuAMZMIQiGACelADRF0dNizBkKsSgDEAhgGscsalrBbKRAL5z0YYMCyQQBVMQzMA5q5yMqW0vVnzYH3oABWAIaBUvQmcrSRB8dSFGYDo6U2czc0tYUgBBXzpHAKl4qkgAWxx_ZxZgNmgAEy1GSQBxLQdYHi0sOhxsiyJJfPoi5xKEygA3HrYq7PQgugAZLRYcLDGYnmBGcqNIqiQZrDmzWAB1dOJB5yXQ8MPomLpoDoImOYDM9FvYJuMAC0bOUCABtAJOGITKjhOgQBpVb5EAC62T6zBwhVgEOcUOcb0qVEEOBEzHEUmq0Likyw4XmAXQdOgOAAylJcFsYsQhLZdlRGDgGlTubFSuo6LYEdcMgtiACtOCwSyAO4GIw4AAUlAATAAGACMABYALR6gBsZoNlAAlDJYABmPV6tE41XqlTa_XGs2WvU6232nUADhd9uVODVhk9usNpotZodgdgOoArC60d85fjiITJiSyWIJNI5WLafSRcRmWyOQkc9zeVh-epBcLS9TxZQmnQABZCmU3dsKpXu6Na2M-hN6pN2lPptERqMar1x31mo3JnXmsNuyMe8fe-N-1ObgDsGblP1gKJQZgA3EA).